# Status of a question from Freeman Dyson's 1972 article

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, lie-algebras, mathematical-physics, string-theory

In a famous [article](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183533964), Freeman Dyson mentions an interesting relationship between the $\tau$ functions of number theory and the dimensions of finite-dimensional simple Lie algebras (section 2). He mentions there that the case $d=26$, remains unsolved. I am curious to know about the current status of this problem.

By the way, if I am not wrong, for bosonic String Theory to be consistent one must have $n=26$  where $n$ is the number of dimensions and the partition function of String Theory is a Dedekind $\eta$ function (in terms of which, the $\tau$ functions are defined). Is this a coincidence ?

I must add that I am far from being an expert on any of these and may be making silly mistakes above or asking something silly.

Thanks !

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9716/whats-the-status-of-the-following-relationship-between-ramanujans-tau-funct

Comment: As for the string theory, I'm pretty sure there is no relation. Number $26$ pops out in many places simply because it is so small. For example, just two years ago it was my age and I don't believe I reached it because of string theory either :)

Comment: @Marek Thanks ! I should have looked at the MO question you pointed out.There are two more questions which are relevant [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99643/why-does-bosonic-string-theory-require-26-spacetime-dimensions) and [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6923/complexes-of-representations-with-complementary-central-charges).